# HTTP POST between computers on different network

Tags: http, curl, ip

I'm trying to send messages between multiple computers on different networks via HTTP.

From my understanding, a computer has an internal IP for their home network, and an external IP for their router.

To send my HTTP packet from one computer to another, I assume it makes at least three hops:

1. From my device to my router
2. From my router to another router with a given external IP
3. From that router to the device with a given internal IP

And that's given there aren't any other subnetworks in the way.

My assumption, therefore, is that to contact such a device, you need a list of at least one IP address. But from what I've seen from tools like `cURL` or `ping`, that's not how it works.

What am I misunderstanding, and how do I go about sending a packet to such a device with `cURL`?

Comment: You can use vpn, ssh socks or dyndns to get this work. you can also try webrtc with signal servers.

Comment: Are you trying to make something specific work, or are you looking for for an explanation of the networking layers under HTTP work? If it's the former, please be as specific as possible.

Comment: @root ideally I'd have an answer to the question at the end of my post -- or an explanation of why such a thing wouldn't be possible

Comment: What do you mean by "such a thing"? Obviously people send HTTP requests between different networks (e.g. your home network and Stack Overflow's network). Are you asking how _you_ can do it with `curl`? How the browser already does that with StackOverflow? How you can send an HTTP request from your home network to another home network (i.e not a network of publicly available website)? Please be specific. And what does it have to do with list of IPs, and having at least one, and `curl`/`ping` showing you it's not how it works?